# Regex search for string like "$12,56,45" using c#

Tags: c#, regex

I want it to search string like `"$12,56,450"` using Regex in c#, but it doesn't match the string

Here is my code:

```
string input="Total earn for the year $12,56,450";
string pattern = @"\b(?mi)($12,56,450)\b";

Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);

  if (regex.Match(input).Success)
  {
     return true;
  }
```

Comment: You should escape `$` symbol, first; using `\b` in front of it is probably meaningless, second (as `$` is a non-word character). Finally, what's the point of `mi` modifier here?

Comment: `I want it to search string like "$12,56,450"` You mean exact string or what..?

Comment: i want to search whole word thats why i use "mi" but i dont know which is work or not

Answer (score 1):

This Regex will do the job, `(?mi)(\$\d{2},\d{2},\d{3})`, and here's a [Regex 101 to prove it](http://regex101.com/r/oD5kC3).

Now let's break it down a little:

- `\$` matches the literal `$` at the beginning of the string
- `\d{2}` matches any two digits
- `,` matches the literal `,`
- `\d{2}` matches any two digits
- `,` matches the literal `,`
- `\d{3}` matches any three digits

Now, for the purposes of the demonstration I removed the word boundaries, `\b`, but I'm also pretty confident you don't need them anyway. See, word boundaries aren't generally necessary for such a finite string match. [Consider their definition](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html):

- Before the first character in the string, if the first character is a word character.
- After the last character in the string, if the last character is a word character.
- Between two characters in the string, where one is a word character and the other is not a word character.

Comment: "prove" is a strong term :p

Comment: @Rawling, why yes it is. Is there one you prefer more? :D

Comment: Nah, you got my +1 anyway :)

Comment: No, i want search like any text after the dollar symbol like "$sample" then what i do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape $ and some other special regex caracters.

try this @"\b(?mi)(\$12,56,450)\b";

if you want you can use \d to match a digit, and use \d{2,3} to match a digit with size 2 or 3.